# MySQL query to reduce server load

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL server running that will be queried regularly through a php front end. I'm slightly worried about server load as there will be a fair amount of people accessing the webpage, with each session querying the database regularly. The results of the query, and in essence the webpage will be the same for all users.

Is there a way of querying the database once, and outputting the data/results to the webpage, from which all users connect to and view? Basically running the query for all users that connect to the webpage, rather than each user querying the database.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to worry.
Databases intended for that.

Most sites in the world run exactly the same way: MySQL server running that will be queried regularly through a php front end. Nothing bad with it.

Well tuned SQL server and properly designed query will serve much more than you think. 
You will need exceptionally high traffic to start worrying about such things.
Don't forget that MysQL has it's own **query cache**.

Also please note that there are no users "connected" to the webpage. They connect, get page contents and disconnect.

Comment: Not in this instance, the data is refreshed on a regular interval when the page is open on a users screen. Similar to ajax but it's a bit of a javascript bodge at the moment.

Comment: @steve still they aren't connected. Do you experience any problem with server load at the moment?

Comment: Theres probably about 200 queries per minute being processed. What do you reckon?

Comment: @steve with optimized queries you may start worrying beginning from 600 queries per minute. However, it seems that for your task a COMET can be implemented. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 2):

You should give the server a try. If the server is overloaded,
you can always try Memcached tool. It can be used via PHP or by MySQL directly. It will save you from querying DB server with similar queries, i.e. the load on server will be decreased drastically.

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage will be the same for all users, why do you even need to have a MySQL backend?

I think the best solution would be to have a standalone script running periodically (e.g. as a cron) which generates the static HTML for your web pages. That way, there is no need for users to query the database when they are just going to end up with the exact same page anyway.

Comment: Because the results are effectively based on time and are pulling data from a database which is changing on a regular basis. I like the idea of a cron, I'll look into it. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

If its a large query with joins you could create a view in mysql with the queried data and query the view, and update the view if the data changes.

Comment: views in MySQL does not contain the result of the query, only the definition of the query.